# Complex Number Homework

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you solve this question without a calculator?

$z^2 = 4- 3i$. Find $z$.

I know how to find the answer to this question using de Moivre's theorem with a calculator. What I do is I start out by finding the angle of $z^2$ by finding $\tan^{-1}(-3/4)$ as a decimal and I then I solve the question using the decimal with my calculator.

I need to be able to do this question without a calculator if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT

Letting $z=a+bi \ (a,b\in\mathbb R)$, you'll get
$$(a+bi)^2=4-3i\iff (a^2-b^2)+2abi=4-3i.$$
Hence, comparing both real part and imaginary part will give you
$$a^2-b^2=4,$$
$$2ab=-3.$$

Two equations with two variables, so you can find $(a,b)$.

Comment: If you solve for $b$ in the second and substitute in the first equation, you will get a quadratic in $a^2$. Once you get $a^2$, you can pick $\pm$ in the square root to get the two square roots of $z$

Answer (score 2):

Write $z = a + bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and expand $z^2$. Equate the real and imaginary part of the resulting expression with $4$ and $-3$, respectively. This gives you a system to solve for the real numbers $a$ and $b$. There will be two possibilities.